# Navigate To New Tab From Link in Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable, url, lightning-button

Currently I have a `lightning:datatable` of items where the last column is a button. When clicked, the button kicks off the `onrowaction` event handler, which uses the `lightning:navigation` to navigate to a new tab via `navService.navigate(pageReference)`.

I want to accomplish the same thing, but with a link. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To open the tab using hyperlink, you have to make changes in your column and in your js method where you are getting the data to show in the table

For example: In column, to display the hyperlink you need to specify the `type= 'url'` and some attributes under `typeAttributes` so that we can display the text we want to display instead of url link.

```
const COLUMNS = [{
    label: 'Click here',
    fieldName: 'tablink',
    type: 'url',
    typeAttributes: {
        label: {
            fieldName: 'tablinkLabel'
        },
        target: '_blank'
    }
}];
```

And then in your js method you need to prepare a URL:

```
    funName() {
            let baseUrl='https://'+location.host+'/';
        this.data.push({
            tablink: baseUrl+ {your tab Id or tab name}, //it will redirect to the link when you click on the hyperlink column
            tablinkLabel: 'go to xyz tab'  //this text will be visible in your datatable column instead of url
        })
    }
```